# .exe files will not open on Ubuntu 16.0.4. Wine Development downloaded

Tags: wine

Operating system  is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Wine version: Development
In Removable Media Settings, a Wine App is selected.
i386 is installed. How do I know if it’s the same version as X86_64?
How do I know if I have a binary package?  “Run with Wine” does not open the.exe file.

Installed WD My Passport Drive Utilities Version 1.0.6.3 but it does not run. Long error message begins: "Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000008 in 64-bit code (0x00000001802ad515)."

A CD-R with X-rays will not open.  Disk contains Fujifilm Dicom Media Viewer but this doesn’t work so cannot see X-rays.

Comment: "but it does not run" and never will. "WD My Passport Drive Utilities Version 1.0.6.3 " requires a windows installation and wine is not a supported "OS". Mind that you do not need those utilities when using Linux: you can do this without the need of software too :)

Comment: So do I understand from you that there is no way that WD, or any other external hard drive, will ever work with Linux?  If that's the case then is it not possible to have any sort of external back-up system at all?  If I understand you correctly, I can back up without the need of software but the back-up would not be portable.   I presume if I go for a dual boot system with Windows, WD would then back up only the files on the Windows installation then?  Excuse my ignorance but I have worked with Windows all my life and find Linux very confusing!

Comment: No. The SOFTWARE you get with it will not work on Linux. The disk itself works flawlessly. You do not get to use that button on the hard disk that creates the backup for you. You need to create those backups with a script that runs at specific times.

Comment: I see.    Could you let me have the script, or tell me where I can find it please?

Comment: Install "duplicity"/"deja-dup" if you do not have it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Will try it out.